# How to list the volume ids associated with the containers created from docker-compose.yaml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have multiple containers running in my machine. Each of them belongs to a docker-compose.yaml file and they create different volumes.

Now I'd like to delete the volumes of containers created from a specific docker-compose.yaml. I can not find anything online.

`docker ps -a`, `docker ps -aq`, `docker volume ls` => None of this gives an association.

Comment: [`docker-compose down -v`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) will delete volumes along with containers; it's usually easier to directly use `docker-compose` commands than to figure out the Compose-to-Docker-object mappings.

Comment: cool that did the job thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to delete the volumes [...] created from a specific docker-compose.yaml

[`docker-compose down -v`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) deletes containers, networks, and volumes.  (Without `-v` it keeps volumes for future use, since they're presumed to contain user data that's hard to recreate.)  You don't need to know the specific Docker volume ID for this to work.

There are equivalent `docker-compose` commands to run most common tasks.  These are generally driven off of the service name (block heading) in the `docker-compose.yml`, so you don't need to know or specify the Docker name of a container or network.